# Heroku suitable for app based on long running processes?

Tags: heroku, paas

I have an app which requires long running processes - typically over 2 hours (recording streaming media). Based on Heroku's [website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#the-dyno-manager), my worker server running these processes will be restarted randomly, at least once per day.

Is there anyway to control/avoid these restarts, so as not to interrupt my long running processes?

Do other paas providers avoid this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know, How to control/avoid these restarts. I was also going through their documentation, They clearly state that "Dynos are also cycled at least once per day, in addition to being restarted as needed for the overall health of the system and your app."

I think, Dynos restart should only take placed when system behaves unexpected or Dynos are found in crashed state OR In month or week to clear cache memories.

You can try [App42 PaaS](http://app42paas.shephertz.com) which monitors your Apps continuously to make sure that they are up and running. If any kontena is found in crashed state, Health Monitor try to bring it back to working state. if unable than that particular kontena is deleted & replaced with a new one.

Disclaimer: I work for App42 PaaS.